# Back passenger tire stuck?

Tags: brakes, transmission, suspension

I have a 2005 Chevy Malibu that recently got an entire new redo on the braking system (new pads, drums, etc) and suspension after hearing a slight dragging noise when brakes were applied heavily. Everything was fine for about 2 weeks, but recently when I start the car it’ll have troubles. If I reverse it, it will stop a few times and not move, and when I push the brakes all the way down again, there will be a click, the car will seem to drop a bit, and then I can continue moving. Sometimes it will do this 3-4 times before I can drive it. If I try to go forward, it will drag for a bit until I reverse, and then it will go fine again. After it does this, the car seems to be slower for about five seconds, but then will go back to completely normal. The rear back passenger (the one that got the new suspension) has way more wear and grime on the hub cap than the others that just recently started appearing. Is there something wrong with the new parts in the car, or is it something completely different?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Definitely sounds like something was done wrong with that repair... have you had it looked at by the shop that did the work yet? I'm sure some of the other users can provide a bit more information than I, but the responsibility will likely be on the shop to ensure the work was all done properly.

Comment: Agree with @kyle_engineer you need to go back to the garage that did the work. The fault could be dangerous, the brakes could jam on when not expected, or fail to work in an emergency.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice! I have made an appointment with the garage tomorrow to find out what is going on!